# Refreshing full sandbox

Tags: sandbox, sandbox-refresh

I want to know if i refresh full sandbox does organisation Id changes?

Iam trying to refresh Full sandbox but before refreshing i just want to know whether org id is changed or not because marketo is syc with sandbox.

Please confirm

Answer (score 5):

The org id will change - whenever you refresh a sandbox, regardless of type the id will change.

> Sandbox and production organizations always have unique organization
>   IDs. The sandbox copy engine creates a new organization as part of
>   each creation and refresh request. So, the organization ID of your
>   sandbox changes each time your sandbox is refreshed. Salesforce
>   inserts the new value in any place the organization ID is used, such
>   as text values and metadata

From:
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_sandbox_implementation_tips.htm&language=en_US